# sql - instead of two rows, i want one row with multiple columns

Tags: sql, postgresql, pivot

Heres my SQL code

```
SELECT system.name,  ceil(sum(((comp.price*1.3)/100)))*100-1 Computed_value, 'total_price' as type
FROM Computersystem system, component comp 
WHERE system.name='Corporal' AND
 ((comp.name = gpu) OR
 (comp.name = cpu) OR
 (comp.name = ram) OR
 (comp.name = mainboard) OR
 (comp.name = computercase))

GROUP BY system.name

UNION

SELECT system.name, min(currentStock) minCurrent, 'minCurrent' as type
FROM stock st, Computersystem system
WHERE system.name='Corporal' AND
 ((st.name = gpu) OR
 (st.name = cpu) OR
 (st.name = ram) OR
 (st.name = mainboard) OR
 (st.name = computercase))

 GROUP BY system.name;
```

Which outputs [image: table]

Now instead want to get a table that has one row with:

```
____Name_____Total Price______minCurrent____
```

Is there a way i can do this?

Comment: Please read about joins.

Comment: Not a very helpful answer, also seems a bit condescending

Comment: I guess I could just write the answer but first you have to write each column in the form of `alias.column` so I could know what column comes from each table. Also you should use explicit joins instead of implicit. Instead of that I told you how you can solve your problem yourself.

Answer (score 0):

If I have got the question correctly, the query be like (on top of the UNION)

```
SELECT name, SUM(computed_value) TotalPrice, wm_concat( type )
group by name
```